# How to install libpng-1.6.37.tar.xz in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, tar

I am new to linux. I cannot install libpng in my ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You do that using ...

```
$ tar -xvf libpng-1.6.37.tar.xz
$ cd libpng-1.6.37
$ sudo bash configure --prefix=/usr/local/libpng
$ sudo make install
```

Remarks:

Compiling libraries is always more complicated than compiling a software because after compilation the results will be stored in non standard places, and you need to specify that when you compile other tools needing this library

You should use the `libpng` that comes with the Ubuntu you installed. Ubuntu 19.10, Ubuntu 20.04 and the upcomming 20.10 all use version 1.6.37 so it will already be installed. Package is named `libpng-dev` so this will work too if you need to install it:

```
sudo apt install libpng-dev
```

That will also take care of the correct location so all other compiled software that need this library will see it.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just open your terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and run `sudo apt install libpng-dev`.
When prompted for a password, enter your machine (login) password, and the installation should go by smoothly.

You should familiarize yourself with [**apt**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt.8.html), as this is the most efficient way to manage packages, libraries and installations on your Ubuntu powered machine.
It's pretty easy to understand.

You can read more about it [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt.8.html).